# Recursive query find cycles that satisfy a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have to following problem given. The table **exchange** contains many exchange rates:

| From | To | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | GBP | 0.91 |
| GBP | USD | 1.24 |
| USD | EUR | 0.89 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**Which currencies exists for which you can exchange money into the currency, but not exchange from the currency to any other.**

For this I came up with a set query like so:

`SELECT To FROM exchange EXCEPT ALL SELECT From FROM exchange`

Now, for the second question I want to answer I cannot come up with a solution

**Are there any cycles of money exchanges through which you can generate a profit by trading through the cycle? Make sure your query terminates.**

I definitely need recursion here. So here is a frame I have so far:

```
with recursive recursion (From, To, Rate, Depth) as (
    select *, 1 from exchange
    union
    select exchange.*, Depth + 1
    from exchange e, recursion r
    where e.From = r.To and
          Depth < k and
          e.Rate * r.Rate > 1

) 
select * from recursion;
```

For that rate condition, I am pretty sure that's wrong because it only checks if the current transition is greater than 1. But what if my transition is smaller than 1 but at some point there is a transition that nullifies this again? `k` is used to terminate the query eventually.

How do I solve this? And is my first query correct?

**My solution (attempt):**

In the non-recursive part I left the names as they were because they are given as they are. I don't want to change them (I know the naming is bad).

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursion (Start, From, To, Rate) AS (
    SELECT From, From, To, Rate FROM exchange
    UNION
    SELECT r.Start, e.From, e.To, (r.Rate* e.Rate) exchange
    FROM exchange e, recursion r
    WHERE r.From = e.To AND
          r.Start <> e.To --stop condition

) 
SELECT *
FROM recursion
WHERE Rate > 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a nice exercise for myself - as I need to polish my rust off in recursive queries, too - so I'll share it with you.

This is a longer answer; it contains a total scenario.

Building an exchange table from the exchange rates of Jan 2021 I got from FedEx - hard-wired in a WITH clause all exchange rates I found compared to US dollars:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS exch;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exch
AS
WITH
one_dollar_is(curr,rate) AS (
          SELECT 'AUD',      1.29433
UNION ALL SELECT 'BRL',      5.36730
UNION ALL SELECT 'CAD',      1.27250
UNION ALL SELECT 'CNY',      6.46720
UNION ALL SELECT 'DKK',      6.10820
UNION ALL SELECT 'HKD',      7.75330
UNION ALL SELECT 'INR',     73.11060
UNION ALL SELECT 'JPY',    103.78830
UNION ALL SELECT 'KRW',   1098.23670
UNION ALL SELECT 'MXN',     19.94120
UNION ALL SELECT 'MYR',      4.03570
UNION ALL SELECT 'NZD',      1.38889
UNION ALL SELECT 'NOK',      8.50960
UNION ALL SELECT 'ZAR',     15.13790
UNION ALL SELECT 'EUR',      0.82115
UNION ALL SELECT 'LKR',    190.76280
UNION ALL SELECT 'SEK',      8.28670
UNION ALL SELECT 'CHF',      0.88650
UNION ALL SELECT 'SGD',      1.32560
UNION ALL SELECT 'TWD',     28.00610
UNION ALL SELECT 'THB',     29.99720
UNION ALL SELECT 'GBP',      0.73308
UNION ALL SELECT 'VEB',1487241.13850
)
-- create an all-to-all conversion table, using the 
-- rates to and from USD ...
SELECT
  s.curr                            AS s_curr
, (t.rate / s.rate)::NUMERIC(18,10) AS rate
, t.curr                            AS t_curr
FROM one_dollar_is s
CROSS JOIN one_dollar_is t
-- dollar to other curr from original ..
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'USD' 
, rate
, curr
FROM one_dollar_is
UNION ALL
-- other curr to dollar from original.
SELECT
  curr
, (1 / rate)::NUMERIC(18,10)
, 'USD' 
FROM one_dollar_is
;
```

Here comes the recursive query.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
change_chain AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS dpth  -- depth measurer
  , s_curr AS start_curr  -- anchor; starting currency
  , t_curr AS end_curr
  , rate
  , s_curr||'->'||t_curr AS chain -- build the "currency used graph" used 
  , t_curr
  FROM exch
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    par.dpth+1        AS dpth -- add 1 to parent
  , par.start_curr            -- keep starting currency
  , chi.t_curr        AS end_curr -- redundant end currency
  , par.rate*chi.rate AS rate     -- multiply parent rate by child rate
  , par.chain||'->'||chi.t_curr AS chain -- keep building the change path
  , chi.t_curr
  FROM change_chain par
  JOIN exch         chi
    ON par.t_curr=chi.s_curr
  WHERE par.dpth > 1 OR par.start_curr=chi.t_curr
  -- no point in keeping those ending in different currency, after more than 1 hops
)
SELECT 
  * 
FROM change_chain
WHERE dpth <= 5  -- limit depth
  AND t_curr=start_curr  -- a bit redundant, but still ..
  AND rate > 1.0001      -- limit to an exchange rate worth looking at.

dpth|start_curr|end_curr|rate      |chain                       |t_curr
   4|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->VEB     |VEB
   4|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF     |CHF
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->AUD->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->BRL->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->CAD->VEB|VEB
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->CHF|CHF
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->CHF->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->VEB->CHF->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->CNY->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->DKK->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->EUR->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->GBP->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->HKD->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->INR->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->JPY->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->KRW->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->LKR->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->MXN->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->MYR->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->NOK->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->NZD->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->SEK->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->SGD->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->THB->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->TWD->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->USD->VEB|VEB
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->KRW->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->NZD->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->CHF->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->TWD->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->THB->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->JPY->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->SGD->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->LKR->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->CNY->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->DKK->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->SEK->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->MXN->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->BRL->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->EUR->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->INR->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->HKD->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->NOK->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->GBP->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->CAD->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->AUD->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->MYR->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->ZAR->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->VEB->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|CHF       |CHF     |1.00010027|CHF->VEB->CHF->USD->VEB->CHF|CHF
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->VEB->VEB|VEB
   5|VEB       |VEB     |1.00010027|VEB->CHF->VEB->CHF->ZAR->VEB|VEB
```

Mind that the query in PostgreSQL, with 5 levels, never came back on my Ubuntu laptop within 30 minutes. I ran the same on my Vertica instance on the same laptop, where it came back after some 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Drop an anchor, by using `from_curr`, as I would name the column, a second time, under the name `starting_curr`, and propagating this very column down the recursion, until the current child's `to_curr` is equal to the down-propagated `starting_curr`.

And, in the child UNION branch, don't `SELECT exchange.*`, but `SELECT recursion.starting_curr, exchange.from_curr,exchange.to_curr,recursion.rate * exchange.rate AS exchange` . Then, see if the iteratively multiplied `exchange` ends up over or under the value of 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I tried to implement your suggested changes, could you check please? I am quite unsure with the stop condition. And I agree with your naming changes, but this is a given problem and Id rather keep the naming for the sake of understanding it later. I have to admit, I have troubles picturing the process here. Do you have a suggestion to get a better hold of this?